# DocuSign API Envelope creation timed out

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi

I'm using the inofficial .NET Core DocuSign SDK (https://github.com/mitchdowd/DocuSign.NetCore) to call the API and ran into the same issue as reported in this question: [Docusign eSign: CreateEnvelope requests timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666100/docusign-esign-createenvelope-requests-timing-out)

When calling `CreateEnvelope` of the `EnvelopesApi` class I'm getting an `ApiException` `The operation has timed out.` from `DocuSign.eSign`:

`Error calling CreateEnvelope: The operation has timed out.`

I just tried to fix it the same way as provided by the answer in the linked question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47685989/5373084). But the timeout doesn't seem to be applied, since the request always cancels after a duration of 100 secs (the default timeout of DocuSign ApiClient Configuration). That's some kind of weird because I can validate the configured timeout values within `Configuration`, `ApiClient` and internal `RestClient` objects. I also checked the eSign version, but this already points to 2.1.0 as dictated:

```
using DocuSignConfig = DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration;

...

Console.WriteLine(DocuSignConfig.Version); // 2.1.0

var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
envelopesApi.Configuration.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds; // 300000 [ms]

Console.WriteLine(envelopesApi.Configuration.Timeout);                         // 300000 [ms]
Console.WriteLine(envelopesApi.Configuration.ApiClient.Configuration.Timeout); // 300000 [ms]
Console.WriteLine(envelopesApi.Configuration.ApiClient.RestClient.Timeout);    // 300000 [ms]

Console.WriteLine(DocuSignConfig.Default.Timeout);                         // 300000 [ms]
Console.WriteLine(DocuSignConfig.Default.ApiClient.Configuration.Timeout); // 300000 [ms]
Console.WriteLine(DocuSignConfig.Default.ApiClient.RestClient.Timeout);    // 300000 [ms]
```

### Edit

With enabled logs like suggested in the comments, I receive the following logs for the `createEnvelope` API Call only if I use small documents.

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2/accounts/5ee37bb4-3236-4fbf-ae75-3c6557ce05cd/envelopes

TraceToken: 15858281-7274-45d5-a225-0d5bef9361e4
Timestamp: 2018-03-27T09:07:13.3371279Z

Content-Length: 2091681
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: demo.docusign.net
X-DocuSign-SDK: C#
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 213.209.125.226

{"compositeTemplates":[{"document":{"documentBase64":"JVBERi0xc5NjcgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDA...GVlMjg+XQo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKMTU2Njg5MQolJUVPRgo=","documentId":"29909651","name":"Vorlage_Uebergabebescheinigung.pdf"},"inlineTemplates":[{"recipients":{"signers":[{"email":"...","name":"...","recipientId":"52058444","roleName":"FirstSigner","tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"documentId":"29909651","pageNumber":"1","recipientId":"52058444","tabLabel":"FirstSignature","xPosition":"334","yPosition":"370"}],"textTabs":[{"documentId":"29909651","pageNumber":"1","tabId":"5e1c8a36-4ea0-416e-a1e6-429fd3bbfb99","tabLabel":"NextDayDatebox","value":"28.03.2018","xPosition":"460","yPosition":"255"},{"documentId":"29909651","pageNumber":"1","tabId":"70c7ce8e-1617-4647-af13-f2bdbcde12df","tabLabel":"InThreeMonthsDatebox","value":"28.06.2018","xPosition":"460","yPosition":"275"},{"documentId":"29909651","pageNumber":"1","tabId":"4eeafb8b-81a9-4f5b-a444-bedfa930990e","tabLabel":"CommentTextBox","xPosition":"328","yPosition":"295"}]}},{"email":"...","name":"...","recipientId":"83811752","roleName":"SecondSigner","tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"documentId":"29909651","pageNumber":"1","recipientId":"83811752","tabLabel":"SecondSignature","xPosition":"454","yPosition":"370"}]}}]},"sequence":"1"}],"serverTemplates":[{"sequence":"2","templateId":"7eb643e2-b4c2-4f7e-89ff-599e7931b928"}]}],"emailSubject":"Bitte Vorlage_Uebergabebescheinigung.pdf signieren","status":"sent"}


201 Created
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 15858281-7274-45d5-a225-0d5bef9361e4

{
  "envelopeId": "b7b37fff-737a-40fb-abd9-4f9ec2373a5e",
  "uri": "/envelopes/b7b37fff-737a-40fb-abd9-4f9ec2373a5e",
  "statusDateTime": "2018-03-27T09:07:13.1800000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

But if I try to test the same code using large documents the call reaches the timeout threshold value and I don't see any logs about this call.

### ----

What am I missing?

Any hint would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you capture API Logs from your Demo env to see more details on the error, you can capture logs by following steps [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging)

Comment: I can. Which logs do you want to see exactly? I can't find any logs regarding the `/envelopes` API call or timeout configuration.

Comment: Is there any create envelope call?

Comment: Also login on webapp with that credentials which you are using in your Api integration

Comment: see edit section in original question

Comment: Whats the size of document you are using when you are getting timeout error? Check [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/appendix/resource_limits.html#file-size-limits) for file size limit, also the JSON Payload request should also not go beyond 25 MB.

Comment: The size of the failing document is 34 MB. Seems to be too large. Is the maximum payload size customizable? Why does the request time out after 100 seconds instead of applying the overwritten timeout value and/or delivering some descriptive error about the payload size?

Answer (score 0):

The link which I shared in my comment for [file size limit](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/appendix/resource_limits.html) explicitly says that maximum size of document which can be uploaded is `25 MB`,  you will get timeout from DocuSign if you want to upload any doc `> 25 MB` directly in an create envelope call.So, if you want to upload 34 MB document then use [ChunkUpload](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/ChunkedUploads/). There is no way to customize payload size, it is `25 MB` only.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification! I'll implement chunk upload next week.