# DocuSign eSign RestApi ChunkedUploads

Tags: .net-core, docusignapi

I have a question about `ChunkedUploads`.

Currently I am working on the solution for this post:

[DocuSign API Envelope creation timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496447/docusign-api-envelope-creation-timed-out)

Can anyone explain how to send an `EnvelopeDefinition` in chunks ?

Currently I call:

```
var request = new ChunkedUploadRequest()
            { 
              Data = <how to put the envelopeDefinition content here?> 
            };

var response = envelopesApi.CreateChunkedUploadAsync( ApiAccountId, request );
```

**Edit**

I am trying to understand how to wrap an EnvelopDefinition object into a ChunkedUploadRequest object.

As simple as possible: What should the data property of the ChunkedUploadRequest object look like? What should the data contain?
I cannot find any detailed explanation on the subject in the official eSignature documentation: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/ChunkedUploads/create/#/definitions/chunkedUploadRequest

Comment: It is OK to refer to an external source in your question, but please include more details on the problem in your post, so those who can help you now, and those that can use the answers later on, see it it applies to them at a glance.

Comment: @Clemens - Please "ask a specific question" - Here is a good reference on what NOT to do, hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I hope my question offers sufficient content now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break the base64 (I tried with base64) string into multiple parts, each part is a sequence. Then below are the API calls seq:

- `Create ChunkUpload` - `POST
  /v2/accounts/{accountId}/chunked_uploads`, this returns the
  `chunkedUploadId` and `chunkedUploadUri`. `chunkedUploadId` will be used
  for more chunkupload related calls, like update more stream on the
  chunk or for committing the chunkupload. `chunkedUploadUri` will be
  used to add document in the create envelope call, it will be referred
  in remoteUrl inside "document" node.

Response will be like:

```
{
"chunkedUploadId": "C4AE9DF7-E3E4-4F3F-B419-29F59647D860",
"chunkedUploadUri": "docusignchunkedupload://C4AE9DF7-E3E4-4F3F-B419-29F59647D860",
...
}
```

- Then `PUT
  /v2/accounts/{accountId}/chunked_uploads/{chunkedUploadId}/{chunkedUploadPartSeq}`
  call is required to uploaded remaining part of the the base64
  document (other part of the string). Sequence will increase like
  1,2,3 etc
- Finally `Chunk Commit` call, `PUT
  /v2/accounts/{accountId}/chunked_uploads/{chunkedUploadId}` to make
  this Chunk available to be used in create envelope call once all the
  chunk of a document is added.
- In `Create envelope` call, you will refer to chunk as below

  ```
  Envelope Definition's document will look like below


     "documents": [{
  "remoteUrl": "docusignchunkedupload://C4AE9DF7-E3E4-4F3F-B419-29F59647D860",
  "documentId": "1",
  "name": "Test"
  ```

  }

  ```
   `remoteUrl` is the `chunkedUploadUri` returned in the first call.
  ```