# How to upload large files for signature using SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I need to upload a large file in order to request signatures from multiple signers.  I'm assuming that I use the chunked upload but, I'm not sure how to tie the upload to an envelope.  Does anybody have an example of how to use a chunked upload and tie to an envelope?

TIA!

Comment: How large is the file you're trying to add to an envelope?  The DS platform supports up to 50MB per file, HOWEVER your actual file needs to be smaller than that since it will get encrypted before being stored (which increases the size).  Please verify you've already tried to upload the document regularly into an envelope and have recieved a document too large error?

Comment: Yep, my documents start at 100MB and go up from there.  Verified.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE accept/check the answer that helps you the most.

Comment: Check out the answer to the question:  [DocuSign eSign RestApi ChunkedUploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875782/docusign-esign-restapi-chunkeduploads).  It explains that "`remoteUrl` is the `chunkedUploadUri` returned in the first call."

Comment: Stan - excellent.  I think that's what I was missing.

Comment: Stan - Confirmed the RemoteURL property on the Document object did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your document is about 18MB or smaller you can use the regular API / SDK calls and BASE64 encode the document so it's included in the request JSON. At this time, the SDKs always BASE64 encode documents.

For documents larger than 18 MB and smaller than 25MB, you can use the regular API calls if you include the binary version of the document using multipart encoding. See the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/requests-and-responses#multipart-form-requests). Also see working examples: [Node.js](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg010SendBinaryDocs.js) example, [Java](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/examples/EG010Controller.java) example.

For documents larger than 25MB and smaller than about 50MB, you use the [ChunkedUploads API methods](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/ChunkedUploads).

Comment: Larry, thanks for the info!  My files are going to be 100MB and over.  Is the limit 50MB?  Also, I think I'm seeing how the Chunked Upload works but, I'm not sure how to tie it to an Envelope Definition so that I can generate an email to signers?

Comment: You may need to break the documents into smaller documents that are each under 50MB in size. Re using chunked uploads: please contact your DS customer svc rep for the details. Also ask them about documents over 50MB in size.

Comment: ok, Larry.  Thanks for your input.  I've reached out to DS.  I will post here when I have an answer.  Thanks!